# How do I use transaction builder app with proxied contract?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I've been trying to use the Transaction Builder app on gnosis (mainnet) to create a batch transaction for a contract that uses the proxy pattern (meaning the ABI is at a different address than the contract).

In the past I could put the address of the implementation contract in and then set the TO field as my proxy contract.  When I try to do that now, I just get:
`No ABI found for this address`

If I go to the address on etherscan, I can see the ABI and the expected read/write methods.

This worked previously for me so did something change that I'm missing?  Or is there some new way to do it?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: could you share the address of the implementation contract

Comment: Appologies, that would have been useful from the start.  Here is one example that isn't working for me: https://etherscan.io/address/0xc1fe9a02fd9caA37Dc3704297aFa0d8501D17749

Comment: I did find a workaround though.  I can paste the ABI (copied from etherscan) into that first field and then can construct my transaction as needed that way.

Comment: Ahh I see, the tx builder was adjusted to use Sourcify instead of Etherscan as this was easier for multichain support. And there the contract is not verified: https://sourcify.dev/server/files/1/0xc1fe9a02fd9caA37Dc3704297aFa0d8501D17749

Comment: Thanks!  That completely answers things.  I'll look into verifying my contracts on sourcify.dev and I have the direct entry of ABI as an option until then.

Answer (score 1):

**When you interact with a proxied contract, you need to use the ABI of the implementation contract with the address of the proxy**